# How can I remove New Button from Search Layout

Tags: dynamic-visualforce

How Can I remove new Button from Recently Viewed Search Layout in lightning experience .

Answer (score 0):

The new button is displayed if the user has Create Permission for that specific object.

If you want to restrict some users from creating new records, then it would be best to remove this permission for these users.

If you want the new button to have a different functionality than standard, then I would suggest looking into if overriding the new button will meet your requirements.

Comment: i get to know this can be done creating new  visual force page and and assigned to particular set of users. but can anyone suggest me how to write visual page code for particular object.

Comment: I suggest you do this Trailhead module.  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals In order to override the button you will need to setup and select the object. Then go to buttons and choose the button you would like to override with the visualforce page.